# Deleting each relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've two models: `Event` and `Link`.

- Event `has_many :links`
- Link `belongs_to :event`

I would like to delete all the related links when the `events_controller.rb#destroy` action is invoked.

This is the destroy action:

```
def destroy
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  @event.destroy

  links = @event.links

  for link in links do
    link.destroy
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stop right there, you don't have to reinvent this wheel. Rails does this for you.

In your models, simply specify

```
class Event
  has_many :links, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

And when you delete an `Event`, all its links will be automatically destroyed.

From the Rails Guide on [Deleting From Associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Deleting+from+associations):

> Dependent associations
>
> has_many, has_one and belongs_to associations support the :dependent option. This allows you to specify that associated records should be deleted when the owner is deleted.